# How to describe three groups where the means of two groups are significantly different, but neither of the two groups differ from a third group?

Tags: t-test, bonferroni, familywise-error

I am comparing 3 means from normal distributions using student's test: $\mu{_1}, \mu{_2}, \mu{_3}$

Results are: $\mu{_1} = \mu{_2}, \mu{_2} = \mu{_3}, \mu{_1} \ne \mu{_3} $

If I want to group my data based on similarity of means, how do I interpret this?

Edit: Tukey's and Bonfferoni's methods for controlling familywise error rate are still unable to separate my data, even at 99% confidence. Surely this happens often. I am still very interested to get some more feedback on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I interpret this"? I'm not sure what the question is here.

Comment: Actually you didn't compare three means. You just did t-tests on three different pairs of means. If your interest is in testing the null hypothesis that `μ1=μ2=μ3` then do one-way ANOVA and if the ANOVA test turns significant, use appropriate post-hoc pair-wise test to see between which pairs of means the difference is significant.

Comment: @Ayalew A What are the appropriate pairwise tests?

Comment: @Patrick Coulombe If I am using the difference of means to cluster my population, how do i make the separation given the above result? Sorry if the language is not clear.

Comment: You could consider Benferroni's test, Scheffe's test, or Turkey's test if the assumption of equal variance is met. If you are using SPSS (not quite sure about other softwares) there are several options for doing pairwise comparison both when equal variances are assumed and when equal variances are not assumed.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know what significance level you are using with your student's test. Let's say you are using 5%.

In this case, the interpretation is easier if you don't use the "equals" sign, as the result of the test is not really a relation of equality.

The test says to you that you can be 95% sure (100% - 5%) that the samples 1 and 2 have the same mean. It also says that you can 95% sure that the samples 2 and 3 have the same mean. They may have an empirical average slightly different, but it is not enough to make you less than 95%. But, if you compare samples 1 and 3 you will be less than 95% sure that they have the same mean. Probably the differences from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3 have summed up to the point that you have more "suspicion" that 1 and 3 come from random variables with different means.

But I think it will help to look at the p-values of your tests. They are probably very close to the significance level of your tests.

Comment: Yes, I think it is solved by the significance level. Seems like post-hoc tests can give me a formal way of defining it.

Comment: "The test says to you that you can be 95% sure (100% - 5%) that the samples 1 and 2 have the same mean. It also says that you can 95% sure that the samples 2 and 3 have the same mean." This is not how a test should be interpreted.